# Any good tool/library for queue processing with good monitoring/management interface?

Tags: scheduling, parallelism

I'm trying to run an experiment that involves transforming a lot of files through a pipeline like this. A and B take a file as input and produces a file, or some text through stdout. C takes those inputs and put them into a database. (A, B, and C are local CLI programs, not servers btw.)

```
File ---------> A ----->
          |                C   ---> Database
          +---> B ----->
```

I want:

- to queue thousands of files and process them through this pipeline parallelly
- web UI (or some human-friendly CLI) that allows me to

  - monitor progress i.e. how many tasks have been processed/failed (task = an instance of the above pipeline for each input file)
  - inspect failed tasks (input, error logs, etc.)
  - manually re-enqueue failed tasks (I don't need auto retry)
  - (optional) pause/resume/empty the queue (It doesn't need to be able to pause ongoing tasks)

(Note that A and B inside each task don't need to run parallelly, and that the task scheduler doesn't have to be aware of the structure of the pipeline. I could write the whole pipeline in a simple sequential bash script that takes a file name as an argument, and just schedule the script for each input file)

Are there any good free open-source CLI programs, or libraries (preferably in python) for this use case?

I checked out Airflow but it seems like it's meant for running exactly the same static task (DAG) repeatedly, NOT for processing a lot of different files through a single DAG... I'm also trying out Dramatiq but it doesn't seem to allow you to easily re-run failed tasks (which is maybe more of a limitation of RabbitMQ?).

I'm not very familiar with these kinds of tools so I'm sorry if I'm asking something stupid.

Comment: Looks like an ETL task. So ETL tool could probably help (BO Data Integrator or IBM DataStage, for example). If not - write a program. Perl would be my choice.

Comment: @WhiteOwl Thanks for the info. I should've clarified I'm looking for free open source programs... Looks like those two are paid software? Anyway I'll look into free ETL tools (I didn't even know the term)

Comment: `I checked out Airflow but it seems like it's meant for running exactly the same static task (DAG) repeatedly, NOT` ? Check airflow. The list of tasks can be generated...